# Changing the default program for an application

Tags: 12.10, default

I have installed [MonoDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) and after that [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29), but when I want to open an EXE file and then double click on it, it always runs with the Mono runtime, and if I want to run it with Wine, I should right click on it and choose Wine.

Well, in properties and in *show other applications* there isn't Wine that choose it for the default application... I have this problem for all types of applications and files.

When the software you want to run is in the right click application (*Open With*),
I can't choose it in properties for the default. In fact, I can't find it in properties, because it is in open with option in right click...

What should I do to fix this problem?

I'm running [Ubuntu 12.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29) (Quantal Quetzal), 32 bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## first of all, add your new MimeType :

from the terminal open `sudo gedit`
and copy the code bellow

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Hidden=false
Icon=my/icon/path                           <-- optional (for the file icon)
Type=MimeType
Patterns=*.xxx                              <--- my file extention 
MimeType=application/myAppName              <--- the mimetype of the file
Comment=My Comment
```

and save it to `/usr/share/mimelnk/application/myApp.desktop` "replace myapp with your app

## linking your app with this mimetype:

use  `ubuntu Tweaks` to link the file type with your app

note:
the wine apps is located on the path `/home/<userName>/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Notepad++`

also you can use `locate 'yourApp.exe'` to find its path

Answer (score 3):

It sounds strange. When I go to Properties I do find the applications in the Open with list.

Right-click on a .exe file, click properties, choose the Open With tab, choose Wine (if not present in the list click "Show other applications" and click "Set as default."

That's it.

Comment: thanx but as i said it is in the open with list my problem is i can't set it to default program for run i'm really confused ...

Comment: no you got me wrong . I said when I click on a EXE file in right-click it shows me wine but I want to set wine as default . like I said in properties it doesn't show wine so I fixed it with ubuntu tweaks file type manager

Answer (score 3):

i have solved this problem with ubuntu Tweaks it has a software manager that you can set default program for each file type ...

Answer (score 0):

Better way to create the  mime type:

```
sudo apt-get install assogiate
```

or see here for article on how to use
http://www.packtpub.com/article/control-of-file-types-in-ubuntu

Then use Tweak to make the link:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Or see: http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-ubuntu-tweak-081-in-ubuntu.html for a walkthrough.

And if everything else fails....like all the above did for me:-(
Use mimeopen -d 
(sudo apt-get install libfile-mimeinfo-perl    if you do not have it)
That finally fixed it for me...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use "Ubuntu Tweaks". Just did the following (after hours of search):

In `~/.local/share/applications` create a `npp.desktop` file, with the following code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Notepad++
Exec=wine /home/<user>/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

In the `mimeapps.list` write `application/x-php=npp.desktop` (for the php types, in my case).

And that's it.