# Setting default application in gnome3?

Tags: 12.10, gnome, default-programs, mono

Question:

I want to set the default program for .exe files to mono-runtime.
Right now, Ubuntu wants to open it with MonoDevelop, which is pointless.

So I right-click on the .exe file, and choose open with "mono-runtime (terminal)", and it works.
However, that doesn't set it as default application.
So I rightclick the .exe file again, click on properties, go to "open with".
There, under "default application", it shows monodevelop.
I want to change that to mono-runtime, so I click on "show other applications", but mono-runtime is not listed in the list that appears there.
My problem now is, in gnome3, it's impossible to enter a path to an application manually.
In gnome2, that used to work.

So my question:
How can I change the default application for .exe to "mono-runtime (terminal)" ?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/224017/62483